# Generic type not bounded in subclasses

Tags: java, generics

```
interface Node<T extends Number> {
    default public T getData() {
        return (T) Integer.valueOf(1);
    }
}

class MyNode<T extends Integer> implements Node<T> {
}

class FinalNode extends MyNode{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyNode mn = new MyNode();
        mn.getData();
    }
}
```

This piece of code is just a simplification of the problem I faced in the huge code base. I extract it so it is easier to focus on the problem rather than the business logic :).

When I write the code, my IDE report me `mn.getData()` return a `Number` type. But `mn` is an instance of class `MyNode`, which is bounded by type "`Integer`". So I expect `mn.getData()` should return result with type "`Integer`". It looks like the generic type bound is not working for inheritance. Could anyone give me some clue?

Modify the code. Is it also a raw type?

```
 class MyNode implements Node<Integer> {
    }

    class FinalNode extends MyNode{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            MyNode mn = new MyNode();
            mn.getData();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's because using the raw type `MyNode` is the same as using the erasure (non-generic) of that type and its supertypes, so `getData` returns `Number`. There's more information at the linked question under the heading *A raw type is the erasure of that type*. By the way, `(T) Integer.valueOf(1)` doesn't look like a good idea. If you have special knowledge that `getData` will always return `Integer` (such that the cast is safe), then you shouldn't use generics at all.

Comment: Ah. It is a problem of raw type. But why it is bounded by its supertype? Since it is raw type, it should not be bounded at all?

Comment: The erasure of a type variable is its left-most bound. Since `getData` is inherited, the return type is erased to the left-most bound of the type variable as declared in `Node`. I think if you override it in `MyData` to just `@Override public T getData() { return super.getData(); }`, it will actually erase to `Integer` like you might be expecting. The takeaway here, though, is to not use raw types. [*"The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of generics is strongly discouraged."*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)

Comment: What happens is that I can not change the Node class and the initialization method.They are both framework level. The only class I can change is the MyNode class..God damn it is disgusting..

Comment: Hi, I modify the change. Is it also consider as raw type?

Comment: No, it's not a raw type anymore.